# Getting Undefined while trying to access a value from an JSON stringified object

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to retrieve a value from an object that I get on submission of a form but I'm getting `undefined` value. I have Implemented an update method whereupon receiving the form values in an object, I convert it into JSON. The output JSON data of the object is shown below.

```
updateIssuedPermit(form: any) {
    console.log("start");
    this.permitData = JSON.stringify(form);

    console.log(this.permitData.status);

    console.log("END");

    return this.http.put(`${environment.apiUrl}/api/liquor/update_permit/` + String(this.permitData) + '/', this.permitData, {
      headers: this.headers
    })
      .toPromise()
      .then(res => res)
      .catch(err => this.handleError(err));
  }
```

**Converted to JSON**

```
{
    "status": "Approved",
    "contactPersonFullName": "jared",
    "phone": "0722XXXXX",
    "physicalAddress": "chiromo",
    "plotNumber": "G6",
    "poBox": "23",
    "businessActivityName": "small business",
    "activityCode": "240",
    "subcounty": "westlands",
    "ward": "kitisuri",
    "businessName": "JUPITER WINES & SPIRITS ",
    "businessId": "12930034",
    "pinNumber": "20012",
    "town": "chiromo",
    "dateIssued": "2018-01-01"
}
```

**Logs when inspecting from Chrome**

[image]

Comment: `var a = JSON.stringify(anything)` is a simple javascript string. of course there is no `status` field on a simple javascript string. what is form exactly?

Answer (score 0):

`JSON.stringify` creates a **string**. Strings don't have a `status` property. [There's also no reason to do `String(this.permitData)` (in the `get` call) when you know, for sure, that `this.permitData` is already a string.]

Comment: the form parameter is an object that contains form values and wanted to get the values from it. I have just realized that I don't need to convert anything.

Comment: @PhilipMutua - I suspected that might be the case. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can access properties by dot of a json object. So don't stringify it.
Try like this:

```
console.log(form.status);
```

Comment: It's not "a json object." It's an object. JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More here.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON.

Answer (score 0):

`this.permitData` is a string (from `JSON.stringify`), so it doesn't have the properties of the object you expect, just the properties of the `string` (like `length`). You need to parse it with `JSON.parse`, maybe save it in another variable.

```js
this.permitData = JSON.stringify(form);
const obj = JSON.parse(this.permitDate);
console.log(obj.status)
```

Comment: *"`this.permitData` is a string...so it has no properties."* Strings have properties. `length`, for instance, is a string property that's, er, fairly frequently used.

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse a json and then it is possible to get properties:

```
this.permitData = JSON.parse(form);
console.log(this.permitData.status);
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, You no need to parse the JSON to string, Other than that you can directly access the object like this:

```
console.log("start");
this.permitData =  form;

console.log(this.permitData.status);

console.log("END");
```